# How to make a change to the routing table persist?

Tags: networking

I am running raspbian and I can access anything on my lan through ethO but cannot ping an internet address.  route -n says the following:

Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

then I run sudo /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 eth0 followed by route -n and get

Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And everything works.  So, how do I make this permanent so I don't have to run the route command everytime I boot the PI?

Comment: please paste the content of /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: How can i do that in the file **dhcpcd.conf**?

Comment: @winnie you should type sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf and then: interface eth0, static ip_address = "the address", static routers = "the router address", static domain_name_servers = "the DNS address". Put this 4 lines one below the other and skip he commas. Substitute the text between quotes by your real numbers

Answer (score 5):

Adding to /etc/network/interfaces didn't work for me in Raspbian/Jessie. I was adding a second route to a VPN subnet so already had used [VMMF](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33929/vmmf)'s method to add the default route; but adding

```
ip route add 192.168.[othersubnet].0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

to a new file created at

```
/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/40-vpnroute
```

hooked on to /etc/dhcpcd.conf and added the route persistently.

Ref:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd#DHCP_static_route.28s.29 and thx [VMMF](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33929/vmmf) for the pointers in your comments.

Comment: Nice.  At first I disliked the usage of dhcpcd for everything, but I'm really starting to like it.  Thanks for this tidbit.

Comment: Since I only needed this for my wlan0, I just added the line to the existing file `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant`. It works on Buster (2021-01-11).

Answer (score 3):

To make the Static Route persistent or you must add the route entries to 
/etc/network/interfaces

Add the static routes in the following format:

```
ip route add [-net|-host] <host/net>/<mask> gw <host/IP> dev <Interface>
```

**Note** This is no longer valid for Raspbian Jessie, as of June 2016 you should edit the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file instead.

Comment: Attention this is no longer valid for raspbian Jessie, you should edit the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file instead (June 2016)

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that the `up` entry should be put against the `iface` entry ([stanza as it is called in the man pages](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en)). So a more complete example for the file `/etc/network/interfaces` would look like this

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
   up route add -net 10.200.196.0 netmask 255.255.252.0 gw 10.200.205.225 metric 1
```

The indent is apparently not required but usually added for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, you have a class A ip local address, great you have an ip address but you have the default gateway as your broadcast address you might want to change that in dhcpcd by using

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

then you type this next part

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.x.xxx # the x's mean your own ip address
static routers=(your routers ip address)
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

i would recommend you use localhost(127.0.0.1) for you dns (if you have one)