# Can't make change to "route" stick

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have this exact problem:

["connect: Network is unreachable" on a working (connected) wlan0 interface](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/connect-network-is-unreachable-on-a-working-wlan0-connected-interface)

So, I'm able to use the LAN but i can't reach the Internet.

And the solution in the question above solves my problem... but only in the current session.

Every time I reboot, it's back to the same. I have to enter the

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

every time. Would it be possible for the setting to be properly saved?

I have configured my router to set the default gateway to 192.168.1.1, so when i do a refresh

```
sudo dhclient
```

the correct gateway is set. But on reboot, all is lost... (I have configured the router to give the Pie a static ip 192.168.1.20, that works fine).

I have also tried the second answer here:

[How to make a change to the routing table persist?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11863/how-to-make-a-change-to-the-routing-table-persist)

but it does not make any difference.

the contents of my /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Please if someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Rather than fiddling with the route, you would be better to set up normally. Post the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file. If all you are trying to do is force a definite IP address you are better to reserve in your router.

Comment: I have updated the question with the info you asked about. I am assigning a static ip using the router. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a "static ip"

You should have a line

```
auto wlan0
```

after `allow-hotplug wlan0` This is not strictly necessary, but the man says:-
"Lines  beginning  with  the word "auto" are used to identify the physical interfaces to be brought up when ifup is run with the -a option.  (This option is used by the  system  boot scripts.) "

If you still have problems after this post `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: I'm not using the wlan at the moment. I'm wired into the router. Should I change this anyway?